# Bottom line divider full width on table row

Tags: css

I have a table css's with this form: column 1, 2 and 3 are inline-block and column 4 and 5 are block. I want a bottom line divider between table rows that occupied 100% of the screen, not of the div.[image: Example]

Now the bottom line divider is width 100% but I want to cover the full screen. The right and left sides don't go all the way, that's what I want, they do go.

I'm using this:

```
.dataTable tbody tr:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute !important;
    height: 1px !important;
    width: 100% !important;
    background-color: #dddddd !important;
}
```

Thanks.

Example:

```css
.dataTable {
border: none !important;
}
  
.dataTable td:nth-child(1) {
display: inline-block !important;
}

.dataTable td:nth-child(2) {
display: inline-block !important;
}
  
.dataTable td:nth-child(3) {
display: inline-block !important;
}
  
.dataTable td:nth-child(4) {
display: block !important;
}
  
.dataTable td:nth-child(5) {
display: block !important;
margin-left: -25px !important;
}
  
.dataTable thead tr {
 position: absolute;
 left: -9999px;
}

.dataTable th,
.dataTable td {
  padding: 10px;
  border-bottom: none !important;
}
  
.dataTable tbody tr:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute !important;
    height: 1px !important;
    width: 100% !important;
    background-color: #dddddd !important;
}
```

```html
<table id="ptp_f8a8c39ec1dfbfd6_1" class="posts-data-table dataTable no-footer dtr-inline" data-config="{&quot;pageLength&quot;:-1,&quot;pagingType&quot;:&quot;numbers&quot;,&quot;serverSide&quot;:false,&quot;autoWidth&quot;:true,&quot;clickFilter&quot;:true,&quot;scrollOffset&quot;:15,&quot;resetButton&quot;:false,&quot;lengthMenu&quot;:[[10,25,50,100,-1],[10,25,50,100,&quot;All&quot;]],&quot;columnDefs&quot;:[{&quot;className&quot;:&quot;col-data_prova&quot;,&quot;targets&quot;:0},{&quot;className&quot;:&quot;col-illa_compet&quot;,&quot;targets&quot;:1},{&quot;className&quot;:&quot;col-modalitat_compet&quot;,&quot;targets&quot;:2},{&quot;className&quot;:&quot;col-title&quot;,&quot;targets&quot;:3},{&quot;className&quot;:&quot;col-actaresultats_prova&quot;,&quot;targets&quot;:4}],&quot;dom&quot;:&quot;<\&quot;posts-table-wrapper generatepress\&quot;<\&quot;posts-table-above posts-table-controls\&quot;>t>&quot;}" data-filters="false" data-order="[]" style="visibility: visible; position: static; width: 100%;" width="100%"><thead><tr><th class="all col-data_prova sorting_disabled" data-name="data_prova" data-orderable="false" data-searchable="true" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 29px;" aria-label="Data">Data</th><th data-name="illa_compet" data-orderable="false" data-searchable="true" data-click-filter="true" class="col-illa_compet sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 20px;" aria-label="Illa">Illa</th><th data-name="modalitat_compet" data-orderable="false" data-searchable="true" data-click-filter="true" class="col-modalitat_compet sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 60px;" aria-label="Modalitat">Modalitat</th><th data-name="title" data-orderable="false" data-searchable="true" data-priority="1" class="col-title sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 78px;" aria-label="Competició">Competició</th><th data-name="actaresultats_prova" data-orderable="false" data-searchable="true" class="col-actaresultats_prova sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 60px;" aria-label="Resultats">Resultats</th></tr></thead><tbody><tr id="post-row-6228" class="post-row post-type-competicions competicions-6228 publish odd"><td data-sort="1616198400" class="col-data_prova dtr-control" tabindex="0">20/03/2021</td><td class=" col-illa_compet">Mallorca</td><td class=" col-modalitat_compet">Trail</td><td class=" col-title"><a href="https://www.faib.es/competicions/6228/">I Trail-Running Son Quint Palma – Night</a></td><td class=" col-actaresultats_prova"></td></tr><tr id="post-row-6229" class="post-row post-type-competicions competicions-6229 publish even"><td data-sort="1616284800" class="col-data_prova dtr-control" tabindex="0">21/03/2021</td><td class=" col-illa_compet">Mallorca</td><td class=" col-modalitat_compet">Trail</td><td class=" col-title"><a href="https://www.faib.es/competicions/6229/">I Trail-Running Son Quint Palma – Day</a></td><td class=" col-actaresultats_prova"></td></tr><tr id="post-row-6340" class="post-row post-type-competicions competicions-6340 publish odd"><td data-sort="1616889600" class="col-data_prova dtr-control" tabindex="0">28/03/2021</td><td class=" col-illa_compet">Mallorca</td><td class=" col-modalitat_compet">Ruta</td><td class=" col-title"><a href="https://www.faib.es/competicions/6340/">San Silvestre Palma 2020</a></td><td class=" col-actaresultats_prova"></td></tr></tbody></table>
```

**Important**: the table is automatically generated, I can't edit it to add classes. The CSS must be done with the HTML of the attached table.

Comment: "Here is an example" Please post your [mcve] here, not on another site

Comment: Added to the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- first of all, padding is giving that space.
- the only thing needed is that set `left:0` and `right:0` for pseudo-element `::before` `::after`.
- for your `.dataTable tbody tr:after` set `left:0` and `right:0`.
- Or I am unsure but your `table` has padding of 10px so set `width:calc(100% + 20px)`.
- below is just a replication of that.

```css
.main {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100vh;
  background: #f5f5f5;
}

.table {
  position: relative;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 15px;
  width: calc(100% - 60px);
}

.table .block {
  display: block;
}


/*for thoes border*/

.table::before,
.table::after {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  height: 2px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #c5c5c5;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.table::after {
  top: initial;
  bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="table">
    <span>a</span>
    <span>b</span>
    <span>c</span>
    <span class="block">d</span>
    <span class="block">e</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but it's not working. The problem is that the table HTML is generated automatically, I can't add the class that you are telling.

Comment: you do not need to add class just see how I am using ```::before``` and ```::after``` to set border.  you can set ```left:0``` and ```right:0``` so it will take full with. Or you can add ```width: calc(100% + xpx)```, where ```xpx``` is value of parent's padding. for your it's ```10px```, 10px both side means ```width:calc(100% + 20px)```.